# Recursive traversal of xml tags is not printing the value of the (sub tags) Ref.tail

Tags: python, xml, recursion

## Xml Document

We have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc id="ENG_DF_000170_20150219_F0010008Z">
<post id="p10" author="Kosh" datetime="2015-02-19T21:33:00">
<quote orig_author="Luddly Neddite">
<quote orig_author="zeke">
<quote orig_author="Luddly Neddite">
<quote orig_author="occupied">
Don't forget the fucking Moonies.
</quote>
The Bushes have middle east oil money behind them. They are owned by such as the bin Laden's and Saudi Prince Alwaleed bin Talal.
That's in addition to the Koch/Adelson openly buying elections.
</quote>
I think the Repubs have a brilliant strategy by running Bush 3. And Clinton 2.
It will allow the hyper partisans on both sides to make the decision as to who will be president.
Because people like me will just say fuck it to voting. If these two represent the very best that America has to offer in the form of leadership, we are royally and truly fucked.
And I am done voting. Not that my vote means much anyway.
</quote>
It's being reported that of the 21 people reportedly advising Jeb Bush, 19 are veterans of the first Bush administration, the second Bush administration, or in a few cases, both. 
Some of the more notable names are Secretary of State (James Baker), his brother’s Deputy Defense Secretary (Paul Wolfowitz), his brother’s National Security Adviser (Stephen Hadley), 
a variety of members from his brother’s cabinet (Tom Ridge and Michael Chertoff).
</quote>
So why does the far left care? None of you far left drones will vote for him anyway, so what difference does it make?
</post>
</doc>
```

---

### Source Code

We want to find the tag `post`. Then recursively traverse the tags `quote` and print the text between `<quote> </quote>`.

We used the following python code. Where we have the call the function `findall('.//quote')` to allow us to recursively retrieve the tags.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re, sys, io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

def search_for_query(path):
  paragraphs = ""
  tree = ET.parse(path)
  root = tree.getroot()
  for i in range(0,len(root)):
    #retrieve data from post
    if root[i].tag == "post":
      #recursively retrieve quote
      quotes = root[i].findall('.//quote')
      for quote in quotes:
         print quote.get("orig_author")
         print quote.text
        
   
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  queries_xml = sys.argv[1]
  search_for_query(queries_xml)
```

---

## Problem

The problem is that it is skipping all the texts except the first one:

```
Luddly Neddite


zeke


Luddly Neddite


occupied

Don't forget the fucking Moonies.
```

---

I think that I missunderstood `Element.findall()`/
the definition is

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct
> children of the current element

So yes I am not looking into the sub elements of quote.

Comment: @sagar the xml file is actually correct. The closing tag is </quote>
So why does the far left care? None of you far left drones will vote for him anyway, so what difference does it make?
</post>
</doc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only the first text node in each element would be stored as `text` of the element. Text nodes that preceded by other child element would be stored as `tail` of the corresponding child element. You can use the following logic to get all direct child text nodes given a parent element. It simply combine the first text node with `tail` of all subsuquent child elements, if any :

```
def get_text(element):
    return element.text + \
        ''.join(c.tail for c in element.findall('*') if c.tail is not None)
```

Quick test :

```
>>> for i in range(0,len(root)):
...     #retrieve data from post
...     if root[i].tag == "post":
...         #recursively retrieve quote
...         quotes = root[i].findall('.//quote')
...         for quote in quotes:
...             print quote.get("orig_author")
...             print get_text(quote)
... 
Luddly Neddite

       It's being reported that of the 21 people reportedly advising Jeb Bush, 19 are veterans of the first Bush administration, the second Bush administration, or in a few cases, both. Some of the more notable names are Secretary of State (James Baker), his brother’s Deputy Defense Secretary (Paul Wolfowitz), his brother’s National Security Adviser (Stephen Hadley), a variety of members from his brother’s cabinet (Tom Ridge and Michael Chertoff).

zeke

         I think the Repubs have a brilliant strategy by running Bush 3. And Clinton 2. It will allow the hyper partisans on both sides to make the decision as to who will be president. Because people like me will just say fuck it to voting. If these two represent the very best that America has to offer in the form of leadership, we are royally and truly fucked. And I am done voting. Not that my vote means much anyway.

Luddly Neddite

           The Bushes have middle east oil money behind them. They are owned by such as the bin Laden's and Saudi Prince Alwaleed bin Talal. That's in addition to the Koch/Adelson openly buying elections.

occupied
Don't forget the fucking Moonies.
```